# Something is using a port, but I dont know what, how to stop?

Tags: process, port

So something is using port 80, I know this because I am trying to start a process that uses port 80 and it wont start because port 80 is occupied, I dont know what is using port 80, all I know is that it is being used and I need to end whatever process is using it so I can start this other process.
How can I do that? I already checked task manager and it says nothing is using port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with the command prompt, you can type the following to see what is using port 80:

```
netstat -anb | findstr :80
```

Then you can use task manager to end the process that is using it (as long as you have permissions).